# Exceptions with Anonymous threads

Tags: java, javadoc

im trying to surround my code with exceptions all over so I wont have any memory leaks.
I tried the following code, and for some reason the exception isnt being handled and i get runtime error.

some code:

```
   try
        {
            methodA();
        } catch (Throwable th)
        {
            MsgProxyLogger.error(TAG, th.getMessage());
        }
    }


 protected void methodA()
 {


            Thread disptacherThread = new Thread()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    dispatcher.dispatch(existingMessagesArr);
                }
            };
            disptacherThread.start();
   }
```

Now if some runtime exception occurse inside the thread, it wont be caught in the throable clauses ?

why is that? does Anonymous thread is canceling the catch clauses?

Thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if some runtime exception occurs inside the thread, it wont be caught in the throwable clauses ?

That is correct.  A `try` / `catch` can only catch exceptions thrown by the current thread.  The code in the anonymous Runnable's `run` method is executed on a different thread.

There are two solutions to this:

- Put a `try` / `catch` in the `run` method to deal with the exception.
- Register an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` either with the child thread, or its `ThreadGroup`.

Incidentally, if you are concerned with exceptions causing resource leaks, the best solution is to write your code using this pattern:

```
    Resource r = // allocate resource
    try {
        // use resource r
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    } finally {
        // release resource r
    }
```

Simply catching and logging exceptions (as your example code does) will not cure a resource leak.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.

The try-catch block is able to catch only up to Thread.Start() method (ie. out of memory). But once the thread is started, or better, *has been scheduled for start*, you will lose control of it.

If an unhandlex exception goes outside the thread scope your JVM will crash. You should surround your inner anonymous method with try-catch.

Hope to have been of help.